# What causes FireFox to shift a float left 50% width over?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a set of divs all with the same width and height. All are set to float left and 50% of their container (the container is 100% width of the page). At some screen widths a couple divs are shifted over 50% as though there is another element beside it.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="pod">
<img />
</div>

<div class="pod">
<img />
</div>
</div>
```

If I adjust the width of the window I can fix the issue. This happens at multiple window widths and (from what I can see) only in FireFox.

I'll work on a jsfiddle to see if I can replicate it to show it. Until then, has anyone dealt with this before and found the issue?

----- EDIT -----
I'm able to reproduce this in Chrome as well by changing the page width. It's just more frequently see in FireFox.

If I change the boxes from 50% to 47% the issue goes away...

----- EDIT -----
Turns out the "split" I'm doing is causing the issue.

Two jsFiddles:

How the divs respond now (I forgot to mention some of the divs are "split". Didn't think this was part of the issue till now)
http://jsfiddle.net/dcp3450/xvMHR/

How the divs respond without the split:
http://jsfiddle.net/dcp3450/Xzrgv/

I think the nested "50%" is causing some rounding with the split items and that causes the issue. Any ideas on if that's true and how to fix the issue?

Comment: are your heights set to a specific value like `100px`, `50%`? do they end up looking like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVyQx/2/)

Comment: The divs are all the same height and based on the image size inside it. All the images inside the div are the same size.

Comment: please provide code that we can look at

Comment: added some jsfiddle examples

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't already have it, get [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).

Then use the element inspector and start removing things from the DOM. Sometimes text may overflow the height of a division element so try deleting text *first* and then working your way up through parent elements.

This is the most I can tell you without seeing the (X)HTML and CSS.

You can also set `overflow` on the division elements as so...

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;"></div>
```

...or...

```
<div style="overflow: auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Every div has the same content (text and image size). And firebug is one of my first plugin installs with FF everytime. :)

Comment: added some jsfiddle examples

Comment: Also, @john, I removed all the elements and just have the image in the divs so any text couldn't cause an issue.

Comment: to which elements? pods, pod, or seed? I tried adding it to each and the issue persists.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the width...sorry at the end of my day. Try the `scroll` or `auto` values for the `overflow` property. There are more refined CSS properties to work with, this is the initial approach.

Comment: Patrick Evans was correct. The 50% (obviously) isn't always even. So some items aren't always even. http://jsfiddle.net/dcp3450/xvMHR/1/